# Use ReDim for unknown size of array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string, integer

I am currently reading and splitting a file's data into 2 arrays (name and age). I have created them both as arrays of unknown size. This is because I might add lines to my data file, but if I dim them in this way (e.g.name()), an error occurs. However I am unsure of how to use ReDim in this situation.

```
Dim o As Integer
Dim name() as string
Dim age() as integer

r = New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\Users\files\names.txt")
While r.Peek() <> -1
    v = r.ReadLine()
    temperary = v.Split(".")
    name(o) = temp(0)
    age(o) = temp(1)
    o = o + 1
End While
r.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    Me.Close()
End Try
```

Comment: Also, turn option explicit on. Your variable temp doesn't seem to exists (but temperary does).

Comment: homework? got the solution and looking to remove evidence?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `ReDim`, use a `List(Of String)` and if you finally need an array, use `ToArray`:

```
Dim names As New List(Of String)
Dim ages As New List(Of String)
r = New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\Users\files\names.txt")

While r.Peek() <> -1
    v = r.ReadLine()
    temp = v.Split(".")
    names.Add(temp(0))
    ages.Add(temp(1))
    o = o + 1
End While
' if you need arrays use names.ToArray() and/or ages.ToArray()
```

But i would use a `List(Of User)` instead where `User` is a class that you have to create which has at least two properties `Name` and `Age`.

Comment: Hi, do you mean  names.ToArray(temp(0))?

Comment: No, names.ToArray which is an extension method in the System.Linq namespace.